# Is it actually Mickey Rourke typing in Iron Man 2?

Tags: effects, iron-man-2

In *Iron Man 2*, Mickey Rourke plays the villain, Ivan Vanko. In several scenes, Vanko is seen to be a consummate hacker, typing away at the keyboard in a blizzard of keystrokes. Rourke's fingers look really fluid as he is doing this.

Is he just that fluid a typist, or did they speed up the action, use somebody else's hands or CGI maybe, to make it look as though he could type really fast?

It's sort of reminiscent of the banjo scene in *Deliverance* where they fake the boy's hands.

Comment: Got a timestamp or youtube link? Deliverance was done by sneaking another musician's hands down the kid's shirt-sleeves… seems a bit primitive by modern standards ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried to find a YouTube clip, but could not. Hopefully someone who answers has the movie on DVD so they can look up the relevant scenes. There are actually a bunch of different scenes where Ivanko is typing.

Comment: I have the movie here, I just didn't fancy the idea of scanning through a 2-hour movie to find one specific bit. [The answer is most likely "they used a hand double". They do that even for closeups of "putting down a cup" because it's cheaper than keeping the multi-million dollar talent around to do some simple cut-away.]

Comment: Remembering this scene, it's pulled back, you see Rourke sitting and typing, with his enormous hands all in one shot.  It's about halfway through, before he gets in own suit.

Comment: Maybe another possibility -  he was just slapping away at random keys, potentially writing Shakespeare?

Comment: I just scanned the movie, and I agree with @HannoverFist - everything consistent with it always bring Rourke hitting random keys.

Answer (score 8):

This was most definitely a slap of random keys. He was definitely not writing code as hackers don't actually type like that at all.  It's sort of a hacker trope that you just spit off a long stream of seemingly endless keystrokes, but writing code is actually done in short bursts, separated by pauses as you try to reason through the most efficient way to code what you're trying to do.  I work in IT, been writing code for 30 years, and have worked with hundreds of people who were very efficient and knowledgeable of code (as well as a few hackers), and not a single one of them wrote code the way it's depicted in movies and TV shows.

Comment: Remapping all the brackets to a more reachable position helps… but not *that* much ;))